# Extract details for past jobs in SLURM

Tags: hpc, slurm

In PBS, one can query a specific job with `qstat -f` and obtain (all?) info and details to reproduce the job:

```
# qstat -f 1234
Job Id: 1234.login
    Job_Name = job_name_here
    Job_Owner = user@pbsmaster
    ...
    Resource_List.select = 1:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=24
    Resource_List.walltime = 23:59:59
    ...
    Variable_List = PBS_O_HOME=/home/user,PBS_O_LANG=en_US.UTF-8,
    PBS_O_LOGNAME=user,...
    etime = Mon Apr 20 16:38:27 2020
    Submit_arguments = run_script_here --with-these flags
```

How may I extract the same information from SLURM?
`scontrol show job %j` only works for currently running jobs or those terminated up to 5 minutes ago.

Edit: I'm currently using the following to obtain some information, but it's not as complete as a `qstat -f`:

```sh
sacct -u $USER \
      -S 2020-05-13 \
      -E 2020-05-15 \
      --format "Account,JobID%15,JobName%20,State,ExitCode,Submit,CPUTime,MaxRSS,ReqMem,MaxVMSize,AllocCPUs,ReqTres%25"
```

.. usually piped into `|(head -n 2; grep -v COMPLETED) |sort -k12` to inspect only failed runs.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of all jobs that started before a certain date like so:

```
sacct --starttime 2020-01-01
```

Then pick the job you are interested (e.g. job 1234) and print details with sacct:

```
sacct -j 1234 --format=User,JobID,Jobname,partition,state,time,start,end,elapsed,MaxRss,MaxVMSize,nnodes,ncpus,nodelist
```

See [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html) under `--helpformat` for a complete list of available fields.

Comment: I forgot to say that I've already checked sacct, but there's no field that provides e.g. the command or the submit arguments used to submit a job, so I've found no way to "reconstruct"/debug how a job was submitted to the cluster.